# Difference between DM13A and TLC59281 Constant Current LED sink Drivers

Tags: led, serial, led-driver, constant-current, latch

I was using DM13A driver in my old PCB designs and it was working perfectly using Arduino Mega. Due to parts shortage at JLCPCB I had to use TLC59281 driver for my new PCB. But TLC59281 is not working (LEDs are not glowing). Both drivers looked similar to me in terms of pinout and pins functions. But I am unable to compare waveforms of Clock, Latch, Serial data out and serial data in pins. Maybe it can be difference in the waveforms which I am unable to understand. Blank pin is connected to GND. VCC and VLED is +5V.

Datasheet of Dm13A: https://content.instructables.com/FIQ/NJPX/I5F7SFVH/FIQNJPXI5F7SFVH.pdf

Datasheet of TLC59281: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59281.pdf

Comment: The only thing I can see is that the LAT high pulse width is 15 ns min on the DM13A and 20 ns on the TI part. The DM13A is level controlled, latching on low level. The TI is falling edge triggered. If LAT high pulse is usefully greater than 20 ns long I think that both should work much the same.  If your existing LAT high timing was very short then it may make a difference. If you can't change the timing then you MAY be able to extend the pulse width with an analog delay. Drive high via a schottky diode across a small resistor. Place a small cap at the pin. Due to ns timings maybe no cap.

Comment: You are right that both should work same. I found the issue. I used a current limiting resistor of 110R between anode of led and +5V. Since current was set to 35mA so i guess that resistor was dropping more voltage and led could not get enough voltage to drop. I removed the resistor and circuit worked. But now i am facing another issue. The LED driver is getting extremely hot when leds are blinking. Dont know why its happening now

Comment: Providing  circuit would help greatly. LED type and voltage drop at 35 mA would help. + information on heat sinking of driver. At 35 mA if LD is at 3V IC dissipates (5-3)x 35 mA = = 70 mW. It would be unusual for anything to get extremely hot at that dissipation except maybe if it has no heat sinking. Again - a circuit diagram will help greatly. Neatly hand drawn is OK.